# How can I redirect this output to $null?

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

I'm using the AWS Powershell tools.

When I run the following, I get a message from the cmdlet.

```
(Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $key -SecretKey $secret -StoreAs "default") > $null
```

I get the following message:

> INFO: Credentials loaded from the supplied key parameters

How can I prevent this message from being written to the host? I attempted redirecting using *> as well, yet the message remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet seems to write that info message to the host program. Something like this might work:

```
powershell -Command "Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey '$key' -SecretKey '$secret' -StoreAs 'default'" >$null
```

When you run a command in a separate host program, the host output of that program appears in the success output stream of its parent host program.

Comment: From The Godfather himself, http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: @kamikatze Your comment is indeed helpful, but I decompiled the assembly and found that it invokes host.ui.writeline which is not the same as Write-Host. Meaning, if it were Write-Host, I could write a proxy command to put the object on the pipeline. Not sure what I could do with host.ui.writeline..

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have replaced "> $null" with "| out-null".  The latter uses native Powershell pipeline control to send to null.

or,

[void](Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $key -SecretKey $secret -StoreAs "default")

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I think it's related to how AWS wrote their assembly such that it writes directly to the UI.

Comment: How odd. I guess if you wanted to keep it instream to a larger script you would need to do what Ansgar suggested but with "cmd /c" preceding it in the ps1. You may have already figured this out but like: `cmd /c powershell -command set-aws... >$null`